# htaccess redirect links with %C2%A0 characters

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect links containing characters like `%C2%A0` on my htaccess file
example:

```
redirect 301 /actualite/presses-plieuses-electriques%C2%A0-les-5-criteres-de-choix_343.html  https://www.mynewsite.com
```

is not working

```
redirect 301  /actualite/presses-plieuses-electriques-les-5-criteres-de-choix_343.html  https://mynewsites.com
```

is working

How do I replace `%C2%A0` and `%E2%80%99` characters on mylinks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `RewriteRule` rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^actualite/presses-plieuses-electriques\xC2\xA0-les-5-criteres-de-choix_343\.html$ / [L,NC,R=301]
```

Note use of `\xC2\xA0` for `%C2%A0`

Comment: It definitely works. I have posted this after testing on my Apache. Make sure this is the topmost rule in your ,htaccess and you have Apache

Comment: oh yes, when I move it in the top of the file, it works ! Thank you :)